# Implementing a split string by delimiter function in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm attempting to write a function in C which accepts a pointer to contiguous characters ending in `'\0'` - that is, a string - and a single constant character delimiter, and then outputs a pointer to contiguous pointers, each of which points to a new string. These new strings correspond to the input string broken at each delimiter character and then properly terminated. In fewer words, I want to dynamically build an array of string.

To do this I plan to use malloc() to allocate the memory I need as I go. The "parent array" will be `sizeof(char *) * (count + 2)` bytes long, to accommodate a pointer to the first character of each delimited substring, plus a terminator. Likewise, each "child array" will be `sizeof(char) * (j + 1)` bytes long to accommodate all the characters of each substring, again plus a terminator.

My code so far is this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *split(char *string, const char delimiter);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *x = split(argv[1], '.');
    while (*x) {
        printf("%d\n", *x);
    }
    return 0;
}

char *split(char *string, const char delimiter) {
    int length, count, i, j = 0;
    while(*(string++)) {
        if (*string == delimiter) count++;
        length++;
    }
    string -= length;
    char *array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (length + 1));
    for(i, j = 0; i < (count + 1); i++) {
        while(*(string++) != delimiter) j++;
        string -= j;
        *array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (j + 1));
        while(*(string++) != delimiter) *(*array++) = *(string++);
        **array = '\0';
        string++;
        array += sizeof(char *);
    }
    *array = '\0';
    array -= (sizeof(char *) * (length + 1));
    return array;  
}
```

My question is why is the compiler spitting out the following errors?

```
split2.c: In function ‘split’:
split2.c:25: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
split2.c:26: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘int’)
split2.c:27: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘int’)
```

My guess is that when the memory for the "parent array" is allocated, the compiler expects that `int` values, not `char *` will be stored there. If this is the case, how do I properly correct my code?

I am aware there are far easier ways to do this sort of thing using `string.h`; my motivation for writing this code is to learn better how pointers work in C.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you double dereferencing `array`?

Comment: Why not use `strtok`?

Comment: length and count are both uninitialised before first use.

Comment: @wildplasser: and so is `i` :)

Comment: I stopped reading after seeing the first two errors. There are enough of them.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Since array points to contiguous `char *`s, and each of those `char *`s to a `char`, I was hoping to get at the `char` with the double dereference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `array` as a double pointer, `char **array`.

```
char **array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (length + 1));
```

As your logic says, you want an array of `char*`, each one pointing to a string. and so `array` should be double pointer. If you do this modification, change the return type also, to `char**`.

If you would like to use double pointers, try this:

```
char **split(char *string, const char delimiter) {
    int length = 0, count = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    while(*(string++)) {
        if (*string == delimiter) count++;
        length++;
    }
    string -= (length + 1); // string was incremented one more than length
    char **array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (length + 1));
    char ** base = array;
    for(i = 0; i < (count + 1); i++) {
        j = 0;
        while(string[j] != delimiter) j++;
        j++;
        *array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * j);
        memcpy(*array, string, (j-1));
        (*array)[j-1] = '\0';
        string += j;
        array++;
    }
    *array = '\0';
    return base;  
}
```

Free this array later, like:

```
i = 0;
while(base[i]) {
    free(base[i]);
    i++;
}
free(base);
base = NULL;
```

Comment: A `free(base);` should always be followed by `base = NULL;` to avoid a dangling pointer. People usually write a macro function to do these together.

Comment: @raj this is a very useful answer; I want to study the code a little before accepting it. About your reasoning that array should be a `char**`: when array is first initialised to hold the return from malloc() it is merely a pointer to a block of contiguous memory. It only becomes a pointer to a pointer after I decide to store some `char*`s in this block later on. How do I reconcile this with whether the type should be a single or double pointer? That is, it starts off life as a single pointer, and then becomes a double pointer later? What if I stored a pointer in the first byte of the block...

Comment: ... and then an `int`, for example, in the next. Then surely the "pointer to a pointer" argument would be void? What is the correct way to think about this? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Every pointer you allocate points to a contiguous block of memory. The datatype of the pointer that you declare decides as what type that block of memory should be accessed. Here, `array` is declared as `char**` and is allocated a block of `char*`. That means, this `array` is the base address of an array of `char*`. That is what a double pointer is. A pointer to another pointer. So, here, conceptually, `array` starts off as a double pointer itself.

Comment: Yes, you may store an `int` value in the pointer array (safe, yet not recommended, as far as size of pointer equals size of `int`), which will be treated as an address value thereafter, similar to typecasting `int` to `float`. But problems arise if you try to `free` that address which is merely an `int` value and probably not a valid address.

Comment: @rajraj Thank you - that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: `malloc` for `**array` shouldn't be `(length + 1)` but `(count + 1)` instead

Answer (score 2):

```
    *array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (j + 1));
```

should be

```
    array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (j + 1));  // malloc returns a pointer, no need to dereference here
```

and then this

```
    while(*(string++) != delimiter) *(*array++) = *(string++);
```

should be

```
    while(*(string++) != delimiter) *array++ = *(string++); // dereferenceing once would do
```

and finally this

```
    **array = '\0';
```

should be

```
    *array = '\0'; // same as above
```

The reason for all the above changes are the same. `array` is a pointer and not a pointer to a pointer.

Additionally, in your code, the loop index `i` has never been initialized and hence is bound to lead to non-deterministic behaviour. Either initialize it in declaration like

```
int length, count, i = 0, j = 0;
```

or in the loop initialization like

```
for(i = 0, j = 0; i < (count + 1); i++) {
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your answer but you should avoid typecasting void*.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @Dayalrai: Nice:) I use `C++` these days and didn't see this post, but nevertheless it's good to know, thanks for the link!

Comment: @legends2k: How can the end of split strings be found?

Comment: @raj `How can the end of split strings be found?`, good point, I would leave a null pointer at the end

Comment: @DavidRF: `'\0'` equals `NULL`, will that idea of null pointer be good?

Comment: @raj, keep in mind that you must iterate through the pointers not through the truncated string

Comment: but in this case he is counting the number of delimiters, he know when to stop

Comment: @rajraj: Like DavidRF says, people usually have a `'\0'` null character to denote the end of a string; so the same semantic would apply to the split strings too.

Comment: @legends2k, David RF: I agree with you. i think value of '\0' and NULL is zero, right? What if there comes a case where one delimiter come just after another?

Comment: @rajraj: In such case his algorithm would be buggy since it doesn't check the distance between two delimiters. Null Character: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: @legends2k: yes, continuous occurrence of delimiters should be detected and no empty strings should be allocated in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (length + 1));
```

should be

```
char **array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char **) * (length + 1));
```

and

```
*array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (j + 1));
```

should be

```
array[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (j + 1));
```

You seems to be a beginner, I suggest you to prefer array[i] than use *array or other pointer manipulation, this is more simple at the beginning.